# dropdown multiple values

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I am trying to display multiple values of drop down and store it to the database. How could I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $form['options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => array('PA' => t('PASSCAL'), 'PO' => t('POLAR'), 'FA' => t('Flex Array'), 'TA' => 'Transportable Array', 'UN' => 'UNAVCO'),
  );
  $form['Project'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Project'),
    '#options' => $form['options']['#value'],
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
    '#size' => 15,
    '#default_value' => '',
  );
```

Comment: Drupal 6 is end-of-life since February 2016.

Comment: They are just using in a one module in other module they are using drupal 7.